# Dual Z Options: Pros and Cons

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis

I have an Ender 3 V2 Neo. I have installed the Creality dual Z-axis upgrade kit (with a second Z stepper motor) and third-party anti-backlash nuts. Only afterwards did I discover that users were reporting Z-axis sync problems developing between power cycles (which I have confirmed firsthand).

One solution I came across is to install a kit which uses just the original Z stepper motor with an additional Z screw and a sync belt connecting both Z screws.

Another solution I came across was using the `G34` command to auto-align Z steppers. Then I discovered that to use `G34`, I would need to upgrade to a third-party motherboard with dual Z stepper drivers.

Both options are about the same cost.

If you have experience with either or both options, I would appreciate your feedback on the pros and cons of each option.

Comment: On my old Wallace, I twisted an unpowered Z axis as part of bed leveling.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used ether of the mentioned solutions. However I currently use this  [BeltDrivenEnder3](https://github.com/kevinakasam/BeltDrivenEnder3)

and it the best upgrade I've done for my Ender3 v1 pro. Easy enough to print and assemble and My Ender now has the print quality of a true pro printer.

Comment: Interesting alternative. Never worked with PETG though; I'll have to investigate what's involved with that. What's the pros and cons of the single vs dual Z variants (i.e., would I need a new motherboard for the dual Z, etc.)?

Comment: I've only have used the "Stock V-Wheels" Variants. Duel z steppers do need a board that has duel stepper support, or you could try a Z splitter cable and up the amps a bit to drive a second stepper in parallel